# What Read Time out/ Connection timeout signifies while posting Request and While Reading Response (Java 8)

Tags: java, web-services, networking, java-8

**Hi**
I am working on an Integration with payment system, so there are some scenario i need to understand what Read Time out Mean while posting request and while reading response.

> As per my understanding when we got read time out while posting request it means our request is not posted to the destination and we can assume request has been failed.

**I just want to know is my understandings are correct?**

Or anybody can explain what is the possibility getting Read Time out while posting request.

> Is that mean request not posted to destination, or it has been posted ?

```
public String postRequest(String request) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Calling postRequest method in " +this.getClass().getName());
        String responseData = null;
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;


    bridgeUrl = new URL(StartupCache.getInstance().getConfigByKey(getUniqueKey(ConfigurationConstant.BRIDGE_URL))
            .getConfigValue());

    if (connectionTime == null) {
        connectionTime = StartupCache.getInstance().getConfigByKey(getUniqueKey(ConfigurationConstant.CONNECTION_TIME_OUT));
        if (connectionTime != null && connectionTime.getConfigValue().trim().length() > 0) {
            connectionTimeOutInMilliSec = Integer.valueOf(connectionTime.getConfigValue());
        }
    }

    try {
        if (bridgeUrl.getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase("https")) {
            ignoreSslCertificateAuthentication();
            httpConn = (HttpsURLConnection) bridgeUrl.openConnection();
        } else {
            httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) bridgeUrl.openConnection();
        }
        logger.info("\nRequest : "+request+"\n");


        byte[] requestByte = request.getBytes();
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(requestByte.length));
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeOutInMilliSec);
        httpConn.setReadTimeout(connectionTimeOutInMilliSec);
        out = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        out.write(requestByte);
        logger.info("API Request sent at : " + sdf.format(new Date()));
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                logger.info("Closing output stream connection....");
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException ee) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (httpConn != null) {
            logger.info("Closing httpConn in exception blcok of output stream connection....");
            httpConn.disconnect();
        }
        throw new ApiRequestPostingException("Exception occured while posting : Reason : "+e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        // Read the response and write it to standard out.
        isr = new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream());
        logger.info("API Response received at : " + sdf.format(new Date())+" Response Code : "+httpConn.getResponseCode() );
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String temp;
        StringBuilder tmpResponseb = new StringBuilder();

        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
            tmpResponseb.append(temp);
        }
        responseData = tmpResponseb.toString();
        logger.info("Response Data : " +responseData+"\n");
        br.close();
        isr.close();
    } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
        logger.error("Error in postRequest(): Secure Service Required");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error in postRequest(): " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (isr != null) {
            try {
                logger.info("Closing input stream connection....");
                isr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (httpConn != null) {
            logger.info("Disconnecting httpConn in reading finally block....");
            httpConn.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return responseData;
}
```

> I have got connect timeout exception while posting request

```
        2016-12-04 18:00:41,814 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10) java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
2016-12-04 18:00:41,815 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,815 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,815 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,815 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,816 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,816 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,816 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,816 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,816 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,817 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,817 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,817 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,817 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,818 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,818 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,818 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,818 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,818 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,819 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,819 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at com.eko.axisweb.axiswebservice.service.AxisCommunicationService.postRequest(AxisCommunicationService.java:86)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,819 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at com.eko.axisweb.axiswebservice.service.TransactionService.postImpsP2ARequest(TransactionService.java:154)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,819 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at com.eko.axisweb.axiswebservice.service.AxisTransactionService.doImpsP2ARequest(AxisTransactionService.java:140)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,819 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at com.eko.axisweb.axiswebservice.resources.Transactions.impsP2ARequest(Transactions.java:97)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,820 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor189.invoke(Unknown Source)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,820 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,820 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,820 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,820 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,821 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,821 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,821 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,821 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,821 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,822 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,822 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:317)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,822 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,822 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,822 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,823 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,823 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,823 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,823 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:298)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,824 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,824 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,824 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,824 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,824 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,825 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,825 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,825 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,825 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,826 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,826 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,826 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,826 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,826 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,827 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,827 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,827 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,827 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,827 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,828 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,828 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,828 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,828 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,828 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,829 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,829 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,829 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,829 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,829 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,830 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,830 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,830 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2016-12-04 18:00:41,830 ERROR [stderr] (default task-10)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

> Read Timeout while posting request

```
2016-12-04 18:07:51,438 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30) java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
2016-12-04 18:07:51,439 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,439 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,439 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,439 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,439 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,440 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,440 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,440 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,440 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,440 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,441 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,441 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,441 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,441 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,442 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,442 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at com.eko.axisweb.axiswebservice.service.AxisCommunicationService.postRequest(AxisCommunicationService.java:86)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,442 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at com.eko.axisweb.axiswebservice.service.TransactionService.postImpsP2ARequest(TransactionService.java:154)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,442 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at com.eko.axisweb.axiswebservice.service.AxisTransactionService.doImpsP2ARequest(AxisTransactionService.java:140)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,442 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at com.eko.axisweb.axiswebservice.resources.Transactions.impsP2ARequest(Transactions.java:97)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,443 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor189.invoke(Unknown Source)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,443 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,443 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,443 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,443 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,444 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,444 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,444 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,444 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,445 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,445 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,445 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:317)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,445 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,445 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,446 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,446 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,446 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,446 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,446 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:298)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,447 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,447 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,447 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,447 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,448 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,448 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,448 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,448 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,448 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,449 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,449 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,449 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,449 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,449 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,450 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,450 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,450 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,450 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,451 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,451 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,451 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,451 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,451 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,452 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,452 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,452 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,452 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,452 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,453 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,453 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,453 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,453 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2016-12-04 18:07:51,454 ERROR [stderr] (default task-30)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It would be much easier to understand what exception you're talking about if you posted its exact and complete stack trace.

Comment: @JBNizet  I have attached exception.

Comment: Post the original exception stack trace. Not your own exception stack trace, which hides the original cause of the issue.

Comment: Hi @JBNizet  i have attached original exception.

Comment: As you're seeing clearly from the exception stack trace, the timeout is happening while doing the SSL handshake, i.e. while establishing the secure connection between you and the server, and thus before actually posting.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet  for the clarification. So in both cases request is failed. i.e request not posted to server.

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding when we got read time out while posting request it means our request is not posted to the destination and we can assume request has been failed.

That assumption is not correct.
Read Timeout and Connection Timeout are different things:

Read Timeout - Request has been posted and maybe processed, but response was not received in time. So, you do not know at time of exception what happened with request.

Connection Timeout - Request failed.

Comment: `Connection timeout`: the actual `connect()` failed, or the network did while sending the request or reading the response.

Comment: While posting request if i will get Read Time out what that mean? In the above code i have provided if i got any exception while posting request i assume it is failed. but while reading response if i get read time out if do not assume request failed.